# Plot Multiple columns against one column in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

First time here!

I have a dataset (60k obs. of 86 variables) variable 86 is a time variable and the rest are just random numbers. I'm trying to plot each column, the first 85, against the time variable. The time variable could be detached from the data frame if needed.

I'm looking to plot each with a line graph since is a time series data set and each should be on its own plot. Can this be done in ggplot2?

Thanks
Justin

Comment: Yes. (For anything else, please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)) Try to make one plot first.

Answer (score 0):

Create some example data. Here I'm just using 3 columns (x, y, z) of 100 observations, plus a time column.

```
dat = data.frame(x=rnorm(100), y=rnorm(100), z=rnorm(100), time=1:100)
```

Use `reshape2::melt` to convert your data into the format that ggplot likes:

```
library('reshape2')
dat_melted = dat_melted = melt(dat, id.vars='time')
```

Then you can plot them in facets:

```
library('ggplot2')
ggplot(dat_melted, aes(time, value)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap(~variable)
```